# Update SharePoint 2010 List with onclick event

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I have a SharePoint list of devices, the columns are as follow, text and choice. The choice is either In or Out.

I wanted to have a webpage that the controller of these devices could click on a slider button that either marks them In or Out that in turn updates the list during this onclick event. I have a JavaScript button already but I'm unsure on how to link the updating the item to this button. I was thinking of SPServices to achieve this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about a custom field type to display the slider? That would be my first suggestion to solve this.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. then use a DVWP to display the slider?

Comment: I was thinking of creating a column based on your custom field type. It will automatically show in the default list view e.g. It will also allow you to update the current item, as you'll have the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As mentioned in comments, add custom field type with Yes/No values
2. Using jQuery, loop through the list items as they're displayed on the page. You can place the JavaScript to CEWP and place it on the page with the List View Web Part showing the items. In jQuery you just find a suitable query to find item rows within HTML, and the corresponding custom Yes/No column.
3. With jQuery, replace the Yes/No column value of each item with slider button of your liking.
4. Attach slider button click event to JavaScript function that calls SPServices passing device id (SharePoint list item ID) and current state of the device. Field can be passed in here if you don't hardcode it in SPServices call.

SPServices call is something like

```
function UpdateDeviceState(deviceId, field, currentValue)
{
    $().SPServices(
        {
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: "DevicesList",
            ID: deviceId,
            valuepairs: [[field, (currentValue == "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes")]],
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                 // Flip slider to new value in UI using jQuery
            }
     });
}
```